# Paperclip does NOT create my specified thumbnails. What am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip, thumbnails

I'm using ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.8, paperclip 2.3.11.
I installed imagemagick some time ago using macports.  To find the version I used:

```
convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.5.6-1 2009-10-01 Q8 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

In my model I'm setting:

```
class Sketch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :style => {:ipad => "786x1024>", :iphone => "320x480>"}, :default_style => :ipad, :whiny_thumbnails => true
  has_many :comments
end
```

When I upload my image, the original size is uploaded but the thumbnails are never created.  Even though I set whiny_thumbnails to true, I don't see any error output.

What else do I need to do?

Ultimately I want to deploy on Heroku, so I prefer not to use any configuration methods that are not compatible with Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for is `:styles` not `:style`.

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:ipad => "786x1024>", :iphone => "320x480>"}, :default_style => :ipad, :whiny_thumbnails => true
                                ^
```